# Different base url for page routing and templates/partials/RESTful API

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

My Angular app is splitted into several subapps. I'm working with laravel which is also responsible for the routing between the subapps.

So there are the following urls handled by laravel:

ModuleX: `/moduleX`
ModuleY: `/moduleY`
ModuleZ, Item n: `/moduleZ/item-n` (unlimited amount of items)

And finally on top of these there are my 3 Angular subapps.
So for example: 
`/moduleZ/item-1/#/hello/world`

Additionally the templates, partials and a RESTful API are served by laravel under the following urls:

`/templates`
`/partials` 
`/api`

If I set the base url with the html tag `<base href="http://www.example.com/app/">` I can use relative urls for templates, partials and the api but not for the routing. I'll allways have to add the module url part like that `moduleX/#/hello/world`.

If I set the base url like for example `<base href="http://www.example.com/app/moduleX/">` I can write all links like `#/hello/world` but the templates, partials and api requests aren't working anymore.

The whole app also sits in a subfolder so I can't just use for example `/templates`.

**So basically my problem or the question now is, what's the best way for handling the different base urls? I don't really like it to prepend the module name to every link.**

Answer (score 3):

Look it's might be a particular solution, but may be you should use filters for urls?
For example:

```
.filter('routeFilter', [function () {
        return function (route) {

            if (some condition mean this direct html link){
                return 'MODULE-X/' + route;
            }else{
               return route  
            }

        };
    }])
```

Comment: Hmm yes would simplify it. But would basically do the same as adding a php variable or angular model as a prefix to each link. I'm actually searching for a more "global" solution.

Comment: Sorry, i have no answer for you. Take a look to use **.run** block with "onRouteChangeStart" event, it may helps, and don't forget that you can use global variables. I mean that you may put any php var into common js global var and access it through the $window service.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you let (sub-)apps know their real base not the parent's one, but you make the server responsible for climbing the path hierarchy to find higher level shared resources for missing local ones. This also makes it very easy to prototype new sub-apps, test changes to common pieces independently first, etc.

In a webserver like Apache, this would look like a rewrite rule (conditional on not finding a file) it just substitutes the same file in the parent hierarchy.

In laravel (according to the router docs) it looks like you can add optional 'directories' to your current rules, i.e.:

```
Route::get('/.../app/templates/{name}', function($name)
...
```

becomes:

```
Route::get('/.../app/{module?}/{item?}/templates/{name}', function($name, $module, $item)
...
```

You could then use $module and $item if you need to test a resource change with specific sub-app/items.

The drawback in making the server responsible for handling inheritance is the independent client fetch/cache of identical resources with different paths. But you can at least choose between large file inefficiency or access latency by using either rewrites or redirects. You can also always hardcode significant paths in production clients later and still benefit from having a hierarchy for testing and graceful handling of occasional errors in client side links.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a simpler way if you use combination of service and directive.

You can implement a directive similar to ngHref which when given a link will transform it and append the given link back. It will be injected with a service which will give it the base url or relative url or anything module specific.

This service which is injected in directive will be configured using serviceProvider in app.config block of each sub-app. Since angular injector have only one instance of each service I think you will need more than one injector or one injector per sub-app. Its unclear whether they share injector among them in your app.

You can configure each service according to module to return different base paths. Which will be appended by directive to each link every time.

With this you can use `<base href="http://www.example.com/app/">` and that should solve your problem.

I haven't written any code but I can help if you need it.